# Clean python tweepy out put for csv file

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

i am collecting twitter data with python tweepy here is code:

```
class listener (StreamListener):
def on_data(self, raw_data):

    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    print data.keys()
    tweet = data['text'].encode("utf-8")
    tweet_id = data['id']
    time_tweet = data['timestamp_ms']
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time_tweet) / 1000)
    new_date = str(date).split(" ") [0]
    print new_date
    user_id = data['user']['id']
    with  open('twitDB.csv','ab') as csvfile:
        myfile = csv.writer(csvfile)
        myfile.writerow([tweet_id,new_date,tweet,user_id])



    return True

def on_error(self, status_code):
    print status_code
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

**Here is Output for Tweets** [image]

How i can remove duplication, remove punctuations, remove numbers in tweets, and
remove words with length less than 2.

Is any out-box  solution avaialble for cleaning the tweepy data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) for a quick solution.

```
import string
text = "I am a 2 tweet."
result = [i.strip(string.punctuation) for i in text.split() if not any ([len(i) < 2, i in string.punctuation, i.isdigit()])]
```

> ['am', 'tweet']

You can use `set()` on the resulting list to remove duplicate words and make this into a `str` again by using

```
 " ".join(result)
```